# AngularJS attribute directive. How to add another attribute directive on 'compile'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like create an attribute directive which add an icon on a button when it's disabled.

[Like this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnabet/1skof5fd/6/)

However, I would also add the `ng-disabled` directive on `compile` (with the same `disabled-button` value)

What is the best way ?

If I add the attribute `ng-disabled` on compile function, it never compile.
So, if I re-compile my element on `link` function, I have to remove `ng-tranclude` directive due to an error. More, my events, like `ng-click`, are triggered twice.

Bonus question: Is it possible to restrict my attribute directive to html elements like `<a>` or `<button>` ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot add directives dynamically to the element that contains your directive. The reason is that your `compile` function will be called *after* Angular has processed the directive's element and determined what the directives are attached to it. Adding another attribute at this point is too late, discovery has already taken place.

There may be ways to do it that I don't know of (and I would be interested in seeing any stable, non-hackish one).

I can suggest an alternative that may suit you: manually place `ng-disabled` on the button, but for brevity and consistency let the expression of `ng-disabled` drive your directive, i.e.:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.click()" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" disabled-button>
```

Directive code:

```
.directive('disabledButton', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
        },
        template: '<span ng-show="disabled">X</span><span ng-transclude></span>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var disabled = $parse(attrs.ngDisabled);
            scope.disabled = false;
            scope.$watch(
                function() {
                    return disabled(scope.$parent);
                },
                function(newval) {
                    scope.disabled = newval;
                }
            );
        }
    };
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3orwupo5/1/

---

Or you can manually set the `disabled` property of the button: http://jsfiddle.net/y5ezvj5L/